# Is there any mandatory medical fitness report required to travel to Finland?

Tags: health, paperwork, finland

I have recently received my tourist visa to travel to Finland for ten days.

Do I need to go for any medical checkup and is any fitness report mandatory before travel?

Also, it will be good if I can get a checklist of all mandatory documents I need to carry while travelling.

Comment: If you received your visa there should be no more ‘medical fitness report’ required to enter that country for no country in the world. That type of documentation is typically required *before* granting a visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly stated by @Jan:

> If you received your visa there should be no more ‘medical fitness report’ required to enter that country for no country in the world. That type of documentation is typically required before granting a visa.

Therefore the answer is **no**, you don't need any medical tests.